# View goes out of order when change screen size ios

Tags: ios, retina-display

I am developing an app for ios. When I build it on simulator for 3.5 inch retina it works fine because I designed it for that in Interface Builder. But when I change simulator from 3.5 inch to 4 inch, components goes out of order. Here I have share snapshots:

**3.5 Retina Image**
Table view is highlighted in red box.
[image]

**Retina 4 inch**
Size of table view is increased but button is at old position. This is my problem.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove autoresizeMask or setFrame for this tableView (maybe height of this table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Follow steps:
 1. Go to your xib file
 2. Select UITableView control from XIB
 3. Then remove auto resizing mask from right side section 
     refer screen shot
```

[image: Uncheck height auto resizing]